# How to map just the values in an object, but keep the keys?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this to convert an object of type

```
{
  3: "#e3e3e3"
}
```

into

```
{
  3: {r: 227, g: 227, b: 227}
}
```

The code:

```
  const colorMapInRgb = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(colorMapInHex).map(
      ([value, hex]) => [value, hexToRgb(hex)]
    )
  )
```

Is there perhaps a more idiomatic way to do it? Maybe a lodash function?

Comment: What's wrong with the code at the moment?

Comment: If it requires lodash then it's not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, there isn't.

Long answer: There actually still isn't a more idiomatic way to do it, but you can do the same using different syntaxes/functions with basically the same result:

```js
const colorMapInRgb = {};
for (const key in colorMapInHex)
    colorMapInRgb[key] = hexToRgb(colorMapInHex[key]);

// basically same as above
const colorMapInRgb = {};
Object.keys(colorMapInHex).forEach(key => ...);

// Reducing the entries into an object
const colorMapInRgb = Object.entries(colorMapInHex)
    .reduce((result, [k, v]) => ({ ...result, [k]: hexToRgb(v) }), {});

// Reducing the entries into an object but reusing the same object
const colorMapInRgb = Object.entries(colorMapInHex)
    .reduce((result, [k, v]) => (result[k] = hexToRgb(v), result), {});
```

Again, there isn't really a better way of doing it, it's just preferred syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through your object and convert each value into `red`, `green` and `blue` integer value inside an `array#map`.

```js
const input = { 3: "#e3e3e3", 'red': "#FF0000" },
      result = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) => {
          const [r, g, b] = value.substr(1,6).match(/..?/g).map(x => parseInt(x, 16));  
          return [key, {r, g, b}];
        })
      );
console.log(result);
```

Another solution using `array#reduce`.

```js
const input = { 3: "#e3e3e3", 'red': "#FF0000" },
          result = Object.entries(input).reduce((o, [key, value]) => {
              const [r, g, b] = value.substr(1,6).match(/..?/g).map(x => parseInt(x, 16));  
              o[key] = {r, g, b};
              return o;
            }, {});
    console.log(result);
```